# Opening a link in Sales and Service cloud

Tags: servicecloud

We are showing an inline VF page on the Account detail page. In that VF page, we are showing certain links. Those links open in new tab in the browser.

```
<apex:outputlink value="/{!m.id}" target="_blank" >{!m.name}</apex:outputlink>
```

Everything works fine and as expected but when we open the same Account page in Service Console then it doesn't open the link inside service console instead it opens a new tab in the browser itself. We want to open it inside service console.

So basically I am looking for something which will work in both cases. How can I do that?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can use:

```
<apex:outputlink value="/{!m.id}" >{!m.name}</apex:outputlink>
```

if it doesn't work use:

```
<apex:outputlink value="/{!m.id}" target="_self" >{!m.name}</apex:outputlink>
```

**Update:**

Look at the following answer it contains required information. Salesforce console integration toolkit would help in this :-

[Can we use a visualforce page as a tab in service Console?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34427/can-we-use-a-visualforce-page-as-a-tab-in-service-console/34444#34444)

Comment: I want to open the link in the new tab in service console. I hope you got my point. For opening in new tab, we use target="_blank". This works fine in normal case but when you open in service console then it will take you out of service console. Which we don't want. We want to open in new tab in service console itself.

Comment: @doga Updated my answer.